# How to pass more than one parameters to render in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

Below is my review.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All reviews') %>
<h1>All reviews</h1>

<ol class="reviews">
  <%= render @reviews %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @reviews %>
```

And my _review.html.erb looks like:

```
<li>
   <p>Student: <%= Student.find(review.student_id).name%></p>
   <p>Score: <%= review.score%></p>
   <p>Review: <%= review.review%></p>
   <p>Created at: <%= review.created_at%></p>
</li>
```

How can I pass @students as well to render for example?

I tried <%= render @reviews, @students %> in review.html.erb and

Student: <%= student.name%>

in _review.html.erb. It didn't work.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to pass multiple parameters. You just need to setup the assocations between reviews and students:

```erb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  # optional but avoids a law of demeter violation
  delegate :name, to: :student, prefix: true
end
```

```erb
<li>
   <p>Student: <%= review.student_name %></p>
   <p>Score: <%= review.score %></p>
   <p>Review: <%= review.review %></p>
   <p>Created at: <%= review.created_at %></p>
</li>
```

To avoid a N+1 query issue you should use `includes` or `eager_load` to load the student with the reviews:

```erb
@reviews = Review.includes(:student)
                 .all
```

If you do actually want to pass additional arguments when rendering a collection (which isn't needed here) you do it with local assigns:

```
<%= render @reviews, locals: { foo: 'bar' } %>
```

This will be available in the partial as `foo` or `local_assigns(:foo)`.

Answer (score -1):

- Reivew table and students are related

In `_review.html.erb` , you don't need use `Student.find(review.student_id)`

```
<li>
   <p>Student: <%= review.student&.name%></p> // changed
   ....
</li>
```

Comment: You could do a lot better at explaining what "Reivew table and students are related" is actually supposed to mean.

Comment: Thanks @max, It's mean, Student has_many :reviews and Reivew belongs_to :student.I didn't make it clear above

Comment: I think you meant `review.student&.name` (safe navigation) rather than `review.student?.name`.

Comment: Yep, Thanks @engineersmnky, i  offen use Angular.